# Can I change the Topology while Storm Task is running?

Tags: apache-storm

As we all know, a Storm Topology can have multiple Spouts/Bolts. When we publish a Storm Topology, we must define the dependencies between spouts and bolts. I am wondering can I register new bolts while the Topology is running?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No this is not possible, once a topology is submitted in the storm cluster, it can not be altered. However you can use the storm rebalance command to  increase or decrease the number of worker processes and/or executors without being required to restart the cluster or the topology.

Comment: Alternatively, I think I can dynamically generate a Topology by rendering a template. Then, I can build this topology and submit it to Storm.

Comment: no matter what but once the topology is active there is no option to wire any spout/bolts within the same.

Comment: is it possible to rebalance using Flux?